# Air Mouse by Accelerometer

Tags: air, mouse, distance, accelerometer, gyroscope

I would like to understand the math behind AirMouse implementation.
For this purpose, my goal is create following simple (or not simple?) exercise:

**Given**: I have sensor data captured from my Android phone, including Accelerometer, Gyro etc. The data was recorded during "digit-like" gesture movement of the phone. We may assume that all gestures where on horizontal plane (say, table/floor)

**Goal**: Draw 2D movement projection (which is supposed to be similar to recorded digit gestures)

I tried straight forward double integration of acceleration approach with several simple addons (like low pass filtering, moving average etc). Also i did some kind of calibration.

However, the gap to the quality of motion caption of $6 air mouse is still huge.

Can someone advice pls how to implement the algorithm used in AirMouse?
Similar algorithm implemented also here, i think https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.negusoft.ucontrol&hl=en

Thank you in advance